# Get webpage source code with alt key code symbols using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get webpage source code using htmlagilitypack. This is my code to get source code and fill into multiline textbox:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
sourcecodetxt.Text = doc.ToString();
```

code is working fine but if my webpage have some "Alt Codes Symbols" then symbol changed with some characters eg: `★` changed with `â˜…` 
My question is how to get original symbol. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `WebClient` and `HtmlDocument`'s `Load()` method so you can specify the encoding:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(client.OpenRead("http://www.example.com"), Encoding.UTF8);
```